# WCF configuration and namespaces

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a WCF service, with the appropriate server and client configuration settings in the app.config.  In a specific setup, the client will need two different addresses for the same endpoint.  Which address to use is determined dynamically within the app and the proper endpoint is selected by name.  I was wondering, however, if it would be possible to add a namespace and prefix to these endpoints so that the client configuration would be:

`<local:endpoint address="http://my.local.address:8005/MFSRemoteDataService" behaviorConfiguration="UnsecureEndpointBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UnsecureHttpBinding" name="MFSRemoteDataServiceEndpoint" contract="MFSRemoteDataService.IMFSRemoteDataService" />`

<remote:endpoint address="http://my.remote.address:8005/MFSRemoteDataService" behaviorConfiguration="UnsecureEndpointBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UnsecureHttpBinding" name="MFSRemoteDataServiceEndpoint" contract="MFSRemoteDataService.IMFSRemoteDataService" />

Answer (score 0):

Declare the endpoint (on app.config) only once.

when instantiating the client, on the constructor, pass the endpoint name and the URL:

```
myWCFService.myClient client = new myWCFService.myClient(endpointName, myWCFServiceURL);
```

Comment: I wish I could do that, but the app doesn't have any way to know what the URL is going to be except through the config file.

Comment: Just add an application setting for the endpoint name and another for the URL (2 strings). After deployment you can modify them on the client by editing app.config with notepad. Make sure to define them as application settings, not user.